# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 2336: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, nltk

Though this question has been asked earlier also but I could not find the relevant solution.

I am trying to use the Stanford API in python using NLTK but got stuck at this issue.

I am trying to run this code in Python. But getting the UNICODE error as mentioned below

```
import nltk
import os
from nltk.parse import stanford
os.environ['STANFORD_PARSER']='D:\\stanford-postagger\\models'
os.environ['STANFORD_MODELS']='D:\\stanford-postagger\\models'
parser=stanford.StanfordParser(model_path="D:\\stanford-postagger\\models\\stanford-corenlp-2011-12-27-models\\edu\\stanford\\nlp\\models\\lexparser\\englishPCFG.ser.gz")
sentences=parser.raw_parse_sents(("Hello, My name is Robin","Whats your name?"))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       sentences=parser.raw_parse_sents(("Hello, My name is Robin","Whats your name?"))
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\stanford.py", line 146, in raw_parse_sents
>       return self._parse_trees_output(self._execute(cmd, '\n'.join(sentences), verbose))
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\stanford.py", line 212, in _execute
>       stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 133, in java
>       print(_decode_stdoutdata(stderr))
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 667, in _decode_stdoutdata
>       return stdoutdata.decode()
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 2336: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: provide a [mcve]. There is not much we can know about your problem from what you have given.

Comment: @Shadowfax Hope editing gives you more info.

Comment: Use `python3` and that will resolve most of your unicode problems.

Comment: @alvas... I am getting errors using python 3.3 also

Comment: can you post the errors in python3 too? Also without the original text that you're parsing, any answer given will be just guesses. Could you post the text that you're parsing somewhere online? Otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, The code you provided doesn't match with the Traceback:

```
sentences=parser.raw_parse_sents(("Hello, My name is Robin","Whats your name?"))
```

But your given code shows :

```
list(parser.raw_parse("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"))
```

So, You need to apply following method where the problem occurs. As you are using python 2.7, using `unicode()` method may help like:

```
sentences=parser.raw_parse_sents((unicode("Hello, My name is Robin"),unicode("Whats your name?")))
```

or (your in provided code)

```
list(parser.raw_parse(unicode("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")))
```

Comment: Yeah... I by chance wrote the wrong Traceback as I was trying different options. I have tried your answer but that isn't helping.

Comment: can you be specific what's going wrong now ? same error ?